# Pipe image output from Graphics Magic to response without base64 encoding

Tags: node.js, http, base64, graphicsmagick

I have a Node server where, instead of storing cropped images, I want to crop them in response to an AJAX call, and send them to the client that way. I'm storing the information of what to crop and how to crop it in cookies and the body. On the server I crop it, encode it in base64, and send it back the user. Here is what my code looks like

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
gm(request(body.URL))
    .crop(req.cookies[name+"Width"],req.cookies[name+"Height"],req.cookies[name+"X"],req.cookies[name+"Y"])
    .stream(function streamOut (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        stdout.pipe(base64encode()).pipe(res);
        stdout.on('error', next);
    });
```

This works, but I don't like it. I was only able to get this to work by encoding it in base64, but on the client side this is seems slow to decode this to an image. I would rather just send an image directly, but I was unable to get this to work. Pipping the image without decoding it resulted in a gibberish response from the server. Is there a better way to do this? Or does the unsaved image have to be encoded in order to send?

Comment: Did you try `.setFormat('jpg')` before `.crop()`?

Comment: setFormat('jpg') resulted in the same gibberish that i was getting before. I'm unfamiliar with fs.createWriteStream, can you show me how that would look in my code?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how you write `node.js` - it all looks like a bunch of dots and parentheses to me, but using what I know about the GraphicsMagick command line, I tried this and it does what I think you want - which is to write a JPEG encoded result on `stdout`:

```
// Send header "Content-type: image/jpeg"...

var gm = require('gm');
var input  = 'input.jpg';

gm(input).resize(350).toBuffer('JPG',function (err, buffer) {
  if (err) return handle(err);
  process.stdout.write(buffer);
})
```

**Update**

Have you considered ruling out the AJAX aspects and just using a static `src` for your image that refers to the `node` script? As I said, I do not know `node` and `Javascript` but if I generate a thumbnail via a PHP script, I would add this into the HTML

```
<img src="/php/thumb.php"/>
```

So that just invokes a PHP script to generate an image. If you remove the `/php/thumb.php` and replace that with however you have named the `node` script I suggested above, it should tell you whether the problem is the AJAX or the `GraphicsMagick` aspects...

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I get home. After I receive the response from the server, is there anything special I'll need to do to display it on the page? For example, currently I just have the AJAX callback edit the src attribute with '"data:image/jpeg;base64"+response' to display it.

Comment: As to my formatting, I split every method onto a new line so that "crop" is separate from "stream".

Other than that, it looks pretty ugly because I'm using multiple middlewares, and the arguments for the "crop" method are all drawn from cookies, which I could clean up a bit by storing them in a variable with a more useful name. I didn't bother doing that before posting because understanding that part wasn't really relevant to answering the question.

Comment: I don't think so but I have never done any `node.js`, normally I would have an HTML `img` element with the `src` set to the name of a PHP script and it would alter the image and send back a *"Content-type: image/jpeg"* followed by the data, so I guess the code above will amount to much the same thing and should hopefully work. I tested it by putting the above in a script called `script.js` and then running `node script.js > result.jpg` and the image was correct so I am happy that the script writes a JPEG on its `stdout`.

Comment: This looks promising. I won't be able to try it until I get home from work, but I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Your solution worked to the extent that I was able to write it to a file, however I was still unable to find a way to stream it back to the user.

Comment: Can you show a minimum version of the code you used on thw client side please? And also say/show what happened?

Comment: I think you need to remove the "Content-type" and just send the image.

Comment: The code I used on the client side is just an AJAX call that makes a GET request to the crop API. On the response, it sets the src attribute of a currently blank IMG tag to the response data. This is partly where I think I'm going wrong, because I'm not returning a URL, I'm returning raw JPG data. When I sent it in base64, I included "data:image/png;base64," in the IMG src in order to get it to work.

Comment: After work, I'll remove the content-type and I'll try to grab a screenshot of what happens when I receive the data. It's very possible that I'm displaying the data incorrectly, I'll get my exact code after work as well.

Comment: If only the fetching/displaying part is giving you trouble, you can check [these examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/). There is an example using `Blob responses` to get your raw data, creating an `img` element and converting this blob to a `Blob URL` to use it as `src` of your `img` element newly created that you can later append to the DOM.